# Creating a new column in pyspark by selecting specific values which are not null

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, isnull

In pyspark I aim to create a new column in which  I select a column value (out of 2 columns) which is not null from . I have attempted with the following code, but that does not quite work. Does anybody have a better solution?

```
def spark_define_column(df):
    df.where(col("col_1").isNull()) and df.where(col("col_2").isNotNull()):
    return col("col_2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) to find the first non-null value in columns.

```py
def spark_define_column(df):
    return F.coalesce(col("col_1"), col("col_2"))
```

Comment: Thanks, should't the dataframe as well as the column to be created be indicated in the function as well?

Comment: @mainman I reused, the method you had shared as-is, ofcourse you have extract out the columns you want to compare as a function arg and use that